# how can i pass this attribute in this shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

**Only catname works. but how can I show other value?**
here the full code: https://pastebin.com/RweNnSP0

[image: image code]

Comment: Please paste the code as text and not as an image. Have you tried debugging this? (ie `error_log($catheading);` or `var_dump($catheading);` before the HTML)

Comment: here the full code: https://pastebin.com/RweNnSP0

Answer (score 1):

You haven't properly output them. You've closed the PHP tags after this:

```
), $atts));?>
```

But, if you want to output a PHP variable you need to open them again, otherwise the text will just be interpreted as HTML. You also need to explicitly `echo` it. So, for `$catheading` as an example, you need to output it like this:

```
<h3><?php echo $catheading; ?></h3>
```

Also, using `extract()` is considered bad practice, because it obscures where variables are coming from. You should omit it and just use the `$atts` array to access the values:

```
<h3><?php echo $atts['catheading']; ?></h3>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. I already try this and not working: https://pastebin.com/RweNnSP0

Comment: You're still using `extract()`. So if you don't manually pass the value to the shortcode then a default value for `$atts['catheading']` won't exist. You need to put the return value of `shortcode_atts()` back into `$atts`.

Comment: hi I remove extract but I got this problem not showing catheading background url: code updated: https://pastebin.com/RweNnSP0 please can you tell me whats wrong with the code.

Comment: You're using `$plistshortcode = shortcode_atts`, which means you need to use `$plistshortcode['imgbg']`, not `$atts['imgbg']`.

Comment: oh, now its working thanks for your help.